# Python assertion error during nosetest?

Tags: python, nosetests

While testing i am getting assertion error like below

AssertionError: Actual Items Not In Expected: [{'handicapped': False, 'first_name': u'JAMES', 'substance_abuse': False, 'tobacco_use': False}]

here expected values are equal to actual . If both are same why it still expect ?

Comment: what changes i have to do fix those AssertionError?

Comment: it  Expected: {u'handicapped': False, u'substance_abuse': False} 
even if  actual is  --->Actual: {'handicapped': False,'substance_abuse': False}

Comment: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "actual" data has more keys in it, which your test was apparently not written to expect.  So the dicts are **not equal**, even if expected is a valid subdict of actual.

If you want only the keys present in expected to be present in the output, then you have a valid test failure here.

However, if you don't mind having "extra" keys in the actual output, then you should write a better assertion, for example using [`unittest.TestCase.assertDictContainsSubset`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertDictContainsSubset).

Comment: AssertionError: Actual Data Keys Not In Expected: set(['benefits', 'address']).
   Actual: {'substance_abuse': False, 'benefits': [], 'address': {'city': u'ram12', 'line': u'1 Street'}, 'handicapped': False, 'member_id': u'987654321', 'tobacco_use': False}
   Expected: {u'handicapped': False, u'substance_abuse': False, u'contacts': [], u'tobacco_use': False, u'member_id': u'987654321'}

Comment: here all expected values are there in actual then why should it thrown assertion error ?   @ wim